# How to getMonth of specific Datepicker dateformat?

Tags: jquery, arrays, datepicker

I set my datepicker to `dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'` and now I have a question how to get only month from this code:

```
var sDate = $('.start-date').val();
```

Variable `sDate` gives me `20.09.2017`, how can I parse and get only 9 from it?

Thank you!

Comment: You cannot parse a date string in that format to a `Date()` object, so your easiest solution would be to `split('.')` and grab the item at index `[1]` - and parse it to an integer if required.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
var sDate = $('.start-date').val();
console.log(sDate.split('.')[1]);
```